# Are gnome-shell-extensions available in the repositories?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

gnome-shell-extensions are very useful for those that like Ubuntu but prefer using Gnome Desktop Interface and not Unity. But they are not currently available on Ubuntu Oneiric repositories.

Answer (score 3):

The people from *Web Upd8* have a [PPA with the latest official GNOME Shell Extensions](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html) that looks promising (but I never used it).

Comment: I am using it. It works fine. Although some of them are a bit buggy.

Comment: I'm using them out of that repo. Works great, no problems so far.